# Wait for async function for event of mocha runner

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, eventemitter

I am looking the way how to wait execution of async function within mocha runner event.
As example I have a custom mocha reporter with one event:

```
    function MyReporter(runner) {
     Base.call(this, runner);
     runner.on('suite end', function(suite) {
      Testlogger.flush()
     });
    }
    mocha.utils.inherits(MyReporter, mocha.reporters.spec);
```

Testlogger.flush() - is a function with callback, or with promise (something with async logic). In my case something like with callback:

```
           fs.writeFile(where, what, (err) => {
            if(err) {
                callback("error")
            } else {
                callback("done")
            }
        });
```

or something with promise return:

```
            const test = promisify(fs.writeFile)
            return test.call(null, where, what)
```

or it can use native JS Promise

So my point, that function should work in async way, probably form of this "async" is not important. I am understand that events work in synch manner, I tried a lot of different options but failed. Also I red somewhere about magic done() function within mocha, but did not find robust example. Of course no problem if I use fs.writeFileSync() function.

How can I force runner to wait for my async function for event ?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into something similar recently.  We were using cypress 9.

Learning from this link: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7139, this seems to be a "design" of mocha runner.

So you may be able to get around the issue with two options.

**Option 1**

Launch mocha runner with `--no-exit` flag.

I have not tried this option, as it wasn't an option for us.  But based on above link, it sounds like it could work.  Though that presumably wouldn't block the event handler functions, so depending on what you're doing may not work.

**Option 2**

Also inspired from the cypress issue link above, would be to leverage a deasync library such as [deasync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync) or [deasync-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync-promise).  So then the code above becomes something like:

```
 runner.on('suite end', function(suite) {
      deasyncPromise(Testlogger.flush())
 });
```